# Get generic method definition of implemented generic class

Tags: c#, reflection

```
public class Target3<T,T2>
{
    T GetTGenericTest(T2 obj);
}
```

In the above code, `GetTGenericTest` is not a GenericMethod, so `MakeGenericMethod` can of course not be used. 
So, when I have a `MethodInfo` belonging to an object of `IInterfaceTarget3<string,int>`, what can I do to work it back to it's non-defined version?
I can't just use MakeGenericType because then I have no way to link the current `MethodInfo` to the non-defined one.

(Pseudo code to keep it short)

```
List<MethodInfo> undefs = new List<MethodInfo>();
void X()
{
    Type t = Typeof(Target3<,>);
    MethodInfo undefMi = t.GetMethod("GetTGenericTest");
    undefs.Add(undefMi);
}

void Y()
{
    var obj = new Target3<string,int>();
    MethodInfo defMi = obj.GetType().GetMethod("GetTGenericTest");

    //How to do this?
    MethodInfo undefMi = undefs.FirstOrDefault(u=> defMi.UndefinedVersion() == u);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a non-generic method in a generic class, it is not easy to "convert" it into a non-generic method in a generic class definition. But this will do the trick:

```
MethodInfo mi1 = typeof(Target3<string, int>).GetMethod("GetTGenericTest");
MethodInfo mi2 = mi1.DeclaringType.GetGenericTypeDefinition().GetMethod(
    mi.Name,
    (mi.IsStatic ? BindingFlags.Static : BindingFlags.Instance) |
    (mi.IsPublic ? BindingFlags.Public : BindingFlags.NonPublic),
    null,
    mi.GetParameters().Select(p => p.ParameterType).ToArray(),
    null);
```

Comment: I think I'll still have to alter it a bit to work with generic parameters (when the method is generic in addition to the class) but this looks more like what I'm going for, I'll do some testing.

Comment: True... if your method is a generic method, then the code has to be changed. So far, i think is the answer you were looking for in your question. If you post an example of your generic methods, I will try to help your some more.

Comment: Thanks but I don't think I'll need more help, I only asked because I wanted to make sure I wasn't going to put a lot of work into this if .NET came with a built-in way to do it but that doesn't seem to be the case. I'll report back/pick an answer when I'm done testing.

Comment: Do you reckon it's safe to simply go by index? Call the exact same GetMethods() method on both the defined and undefined class, and then in the result of the `defined` class get the IndexOf(`MethodInfo`) and use that index to return the `MethodInfo` from the results of the `undefined` class?

Comment: @natli: I do not follow you. One thing I can tell you: you cannot call a member of an undefined generic class.

Comment: I tested it and it works just fine so I suppose it's all good, thanks for your help.